# Using Linq on datatable that contain numeric field

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ibm-midrange

I am using LINQ on datatable containing a Group By clause.
One of the fields is numeric. It is defined as Numeric 6,0 in AS400.

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(it => new
    {
        status = it.Field<string>("status"),
        CommentNo = it.Field<?????>("commentNo")
    })...
```

commentNo is the number and I do not know what type should be defined:

```
   CommentNo = it.Field<int>("commentNo") // does not work
```

I am getting the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in 
System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll. Additional information: Specified cast is
not valid.
```

Comment: Use `decimal` instead of `int`.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: Whenever in doubt - you can use `object`, compile, put a breakpoint and use the watch window to see what the actual type of the object is. Then you can replace `object` with the actual type.

Comment: Yes thanks, it shows me the type adding to watch: CommentNo.GetType()